# Show elements depending on html value of a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to accomplish the following with jquery :

When I click on this link

```
<a href="#">Cars</a>
```

I would like all divs like those

```
<div class="product">
    <div class="category">Cars</div>
</div>
```

to do something.

You get the idea, I have a menu with a list of categories, and a list of products, each containing a div with the category name, and I would like to make them hide/show.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure if i fully understand your question, but if you want the div class="category" cars to appear when cars link is clicked, follow this:

```
$("#menu a").click(function() {
   var value = $(this).html();

   $.each($(".category"), function(i, item) {
     if ($(item).html() == value) {
         $(item).parent().hide();
     }

   });
});
```

if you want to hide the div just replace `$(item).show()`; with `$(item).hide();`

Comment: Yes, thanks that's the idea, except I wanted to hide the parent div (the "product") not the "category" one. I managed to do that by doing $(item).parent().show(); instead of $(item).show();

ps. I think there is a typo in your code, it should be if ($(item).html() == value) { instead of if ($(item).html == value) {

Comment: yes, it was a typo, thank you, I updated my answer with your final needs, good thing i helped you.. see you around! :) can you mark my answers as accepted?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming:

```
<a href="#" class="highlight">Cars</a>
```

then:

```
$("a.highlight").click(function() {
  $("div.category").removeClass("category")
    .filter(":contains(" + $(this).text() + ")").addClass("highlight");
  return false;
});
```

What this does is add the `category` class to any `category` dvis that contain the text of the link. This can be modified to modify the parent `product` div if you want to do it that way too.

It works by first removing the class `highlight` from all `category` divs and then adding it to the ones that require it.

Answer (score 1):

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/ucewo3/11 **SOURCE:** http://jsbin.com/ucewo3/11/edit

```
    $('a').click( function(e) {
       var search_term = $.trim($(this).text()); //trim text
      $('.category').each(function() {  
      ($(this).text().search(new RegExp( search_term , 'i')) < 0 )//upper & lower
        ? $(this).parent().hide() : $(this).parent().show();  
       });  
    });
```

This keep the **text** inside the `<a>` tag and make a search into the `<div class="category">` if the `<a>` text match with `.category` text it show the related `.product` content!

**NOTE:**

1. the script match both **Uppercase** and **Lowercase** chars

   example match `Cars` as well as `cars` and `CARS`
2. also match **spaced text** like `<a>   cars    </a>` as well as `<a>cars</a>` and `<a>cars  </a>`
3. match also **tagged text** like `<div class="category"><span>cars</span></div>`

​
    ​

Comment: Interesting script ! Thanks for sharing